# How to write date time values in core plot graph in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, core-plot

I have implemented core plot graph using link http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/10/adding-charts-to-your-iphone-ipad-app-using-core-plot/

**In this example author used both float values for x,y points**

but now ***i need to use time values for y axis points how should i wrote code to assign x,y points***

```
AppDelegate *app =  (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray * times = app.timesArray;
NSMutableArray * painlevels = app.PainlevelsArray;
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
//Xand y Points to draw a graph
 NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=0 ; i< [painlevels count]; i++)
{
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([[painlevels objectAtIndex:i]floatValue] , [[times objectAtIndex:i]floatValue])]];
}
```

**//X,y points for previous values float values in author example**

/*
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(@"fd", 0)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-8, 10)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-6, 40)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-5, 20)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 50)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 3)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 18)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(6, 36)]];
    [data addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(9, 66)]];*/

```
self.scatterPlot = [[ScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:data];
[self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];
```

Answer (score 2):

Core Plot includes two different ways to format date values. `CPTTimeFormatter` formats dates based on a time interval given in seconds relative to a reference date. `CPTCalendarFormatter` lets you specify the interval (days, months, hours, etc.).

The DatePlot and Plot Gallery example apps demonstrate how to use `CPTTimeFormatter`. See this  [discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/coreplot-discuss/grjwkFnNKvY) for an example of how to use `CPTCalendarFormatter`.

`CPTCalendarFormatter` is really great but it is not available in version 1.0. You can add it to your project from the link referenced above.